# File Upload Using SpringMvc why Use Jsp

Tags: html, file, jsp, spring-mvc

can i do file upload in spring without using jsp and by using just html pages 
ie is there any alternative to using

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

for binding the Command name to the Form 
ie without using this

Also Please Explain what is the need for binding the Command Name with the Form?

Comment: can jspx be an alternative for you?

Comment: i am basically looking at running the application in mobile devices so i am not sure whether i can proceed with jsp or even jspx for that matter

Answer (score 0):

U mean static html pages in combination with Spring? ... is like to butter a bread with the sword Excalibur, **indeed it is possible** but the members of the round table will ask what you try to do.

The basic problem is: Spring like to know what component actually is bound to spring. Im not sure if spring respects plain html-upload-form-tags.

(As a member of the round-table do i have to ask what you try to do)